# Frontend "Edit" link for article not working in Joomla 3.3.3

Tags: php, mysql, windows, joomla, edit

Clicking the frontend "edit" link for an article does not work, either for articles I create or other articles (my account is a super admin). I tried different templates and the edit link doesn't work using either of them (Protostar and Yootheme Avenue). The screen reloads the article without showing the editor. My initial thought was that it's a permissions problem on the file system but not sure where to start troubleshooting. This site is on an internal Windows server (not public facing) and I'm not sure how to set permissions compared to a Unix / Linux server if that's the problem.

If I create an article on the frontend using the "Create an Article" menu item, then the editor DOES appear and I can save the article. But when I browse to that new article then click the edit link, I still cannot edit the article. The page reloads without showing the editor.

Any ideas?

My Joomla setup is:

Joomla! 3.3.3
Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1
MySQL 5.6.18
PHP 5.3.28
Apache 2.2.25

Scott

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your browser console? Might be a conflicting Javascript file

Comment: No errors in browser console. The page reloads without going into edit screen with the editor.

Comment: Have have you edited any core Joomla files or tried removing any files?

Comment: I edited the configuration.php, of course, with website properties. I added a custom theme for the template but that only contains CSS files.

Comment: I found the issue. It's an SSO issue. I've contacted the developer of that plugin. Thanks for troubleshooting with me.